# openvpn clustering and throttle network speed

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn, network-speed

I am currently using Ubuntu for an OpenVPN server and it is working well.

Each connected device can get an IP Address from the DHCP provided by the OpenVPN server.
But for our project, is there a way we can cluster users and then throttle their speed depending on the setup

for example:

> IP1, IP2, IP3 should be called as cluster 1.
>
> IP 4, IP5, IP6 is cluster 2.
>
> And then for Cluster 1, they can share a network speed of 20 Mbps.
>
> While for Cluster 2, they can share a network speed of 30 Mbps.

For the clustering, it should depend on the certificate used to access OpenVPN.

Meaning, all IP addresses being added to the cluster 1 is based from the client certificate they used which is CERT1.

While for users who accessed OpenVPN via CERT2, will be classified under cluster 2.

Comment: Use netfilter via `iptables` or `nftables`.

Comment: But how do I cluster IP Addresses?

Comment: http://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html